# Is it possible to make R put a number in a column counting up each instance of a value?

Tags: r

Basically, I have a dataset of bird bands, with one or more instances of each color.band code per year. I want to have a column that counts up one digit each time a given color.band code occurs. So if XXXXXX occurs two times, the first one would have a 1 next to it and the second one a 2. If YYYYYY had only one occurrence it would only have a 1, and so on. I'm not sure how to begin doing this. How could I do this? Thank you!

[image: part of my dataset showing the color.bands in question]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`. We cannot copy/paste data from images.

Comment: Do you want to count `color.band` across all years or within years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ave`

```
df1$Count <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(color.band), color.band, FUN = seq_along))
```

---

Or using `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df1$Count <- rowid(df1$color.band)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution, where `mydata` is your dataframe.

If you want to count across all years:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  group_by(color.band) %>% 
  mutate(Count = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

If you want to count within years:

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(year, color.band) %>% 
  mutate(Count = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```